# google-cloud-speech speech.types.RecognitionConfig

Tags: config, google-cloud-speech

I am current running on Debian 8 Jessie with Python 2.7 and the current google-cloud-speech and storage (pip'd in with upgrade today).  When I attempt to config it fails with:

ValueError: Protocol message RecognitionConfig has no "enable_automatic_punctuation" field.

from this call:

```
config = speech.types.RecognitionConfig(
    encoding=speech.enums.RecognitionConfig.AudioEncoding.LINEAR16,
    sample_rate_hertz=8000,
    language_code='en-US',
    # Enable automatic punctuation
    enable_automatic_punctuation=True)
```

The call was directly copy/paste'd from "https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/automatic-punctuation#speech-enhanced-model-python".

Huh?

Comment: did you `from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enable_automatic_punctuation` is only available if you import `speech_v1p1beta1` instead of `speech_v1`. Compare the documentation for `RecognitionConfig` for both [beta](http://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/speech/gapic/v1p1beta1/types.html?highlight=use_enhanced#google.cloud.speech_v1p1beta1.types.RecognitionConfig.enable_automatic_punctuation) and [non beta](https://google-cloud-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/speech/gapic/v1/types.html?highlight=RecognitionConfig).

Also, in the very same example that you have linked, if you click on [View on Github](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/blob/master/speech/cloud-client/beta_snippets.py), you can see the following import:

`from google.cloud import speech_v1p1beta1 as speech`

Also, [related to this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50076467/using-enhanced-model-in-google-cloud-speech-api/50099176#50099176).

**EDIT**:

Also, that code is on Python 3, and you are using Python 2.7, be aware of that.

Comment: Ah Haw!!!!  Python3 makes it possible to execute successfully.  Much obliged sir.